# Spring 4 MVC with Ajax JSON POST and Spring Security

Tags: json, ajax, spring, post, spring-security

I have been searching for a project setup with spring 4 mvc and spring security and AJAX post. Unfortunately I have not found any. Samples I found work without spring security. If anyone knows any link or configurations with dependencies, please let me know.

thanks

Comment: see you didn't find example directly for your requirement, 1st you need to find example of spring 4 MVC with spring security 
http://www.journaldev.com/8718/spring-4-security-login-logout-inmemory-example
after you need find Ajax json example and integrate as per your requirement

Comment: I found http://www.tutorialsdesk.com/2016/01/spring-rest-hello-world-json-tutorial.html this link useful for JSON

Comment: and this http://www.tutorialsdesk.com/2016/02/spring-mvc-security-with-in-memory.html for spring security example

Comment: spring 4 mvc and security setup is working. I have also tried <sec:csrfMetaTags/> in the jsp and added var csrfParameter = $("meta[name='_csrf_parameter']").attr("content");
 var csrfHeader = $("meta[name='_csrf_header']").attr("content");
 var csrfToken = $("meta[name='_csrf']").attr("content"); data[csrfParameter] = csrfToken;
 headers[csrfHeader] = csrfToken; while sending via ajax post